# Is $\{f_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ necessarily a Cauchy sequence in $L^2([0, 1])$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{f_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of continuous function defined
on the interval $[0, 1]$. We assume that for every $x ∈ [0, 1]$, the sequence
of real numbers $\{f_n(x)\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy. Is $\{f_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ necessarily a Cauchy
sequence in $L^2([0, 1])$?

Comment: So the question is in essence, "is every pointwise convergent sequence $L^2$-convergent?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_n(0)=0$ ,$f_n(x)=\sqrt n $ for  $ x \in (\frac 1 {n^{2}},\frac 1 n)$, $0$ for $x >\frac 1 n +\frac 1 {n^{2}}$ and linear between $\frac 1 n $ and $\frac 1 n+ \frac 1 {n^{2}}$ and also between $0$ and $\frac 1 {n^{2}}$. This is a counterexample. This sequence tends to $0$ at every point. If it is Cauchy in $L^{2}$ it will converge in $L^{2}$ but it can only converge to $0$ because pointwise limit is $0$. But $\|f_n-0\|_2$ does not tend to $0$.

Comment: could you elaborate on how you constructed that?

Comment: That's not continuous on $[0,1]$ but it can be easily adjusted to make it so.

Comment: @Thomas You want a function which pointwise converges, but whose integral doesn't converge. The standard way is to make a sequence of functions with smaller and smaller support but larger and larger value. This is the simplest such sequence.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks for the comment. I had noticed the requirement that the functions had to be continuous. I think I have modified my example to take care of this problem.

Comment: Thank you all for working on this, especially by using an easy function to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for a counterexample. For any $n\geq 1$, consider a piecewise linear function $f_n$ defined by joining the points $(0,0)$, $(\frac{1}{2n},a_n)$, $(\frac{1}{n},0)$, and $(1,0)$ where $a_n>0$ has to be chosen. Then $f_n(x)\to 0$ for any $x\in [0,1]$ (and $\{f_n(x)\}_{n\geq 1}$ is a Cauchy sequence). Choose  $a_n$ in such a way that $a_n\to +\infty$ and
$\int_0^1 f_n^2(x)\, dx$ is not convergent.

Comment: thanks for your note!

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_n(x) = n^2x^n\sqrt {1-x}.$ Then $f_n(x)\to 0 $ for every $x\in [0,1],$ yet $\int_0^1 f_n^2 \to \infty.$

Comment: Thanks for the example!